# Как использовать scopes Yii 1.1.5

Tags: yii, activerecord

Есть моделька со своим scopes, через которую я получаю определенные записи

```
class MainTsee extends CActiveRecord
{

    public function tableName()
  {
     return '{{main_tsee}}';
  }

  public function scopes() {
        return array(
           'pupular'=>array (
               'order'=>'look_count'
           ), 
        );
    }
```

Эта моделька связана с другой вот так

```
class Country extends CActiveRecord
{
   public function tableName()
   {
       return '{{country}}';
   }

  public function rules()
{   //.. some rules  }


public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
return array( 'see_places'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MainTsee', 'id_country'),
```

Вопрос как мне получать значения заданные в scopes через связи?

Обычно без связей так получаю  `MainTsee::model()->popular->findAll();` 
А как сделать такую выборку используя связи $model->see_places->popular - например

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь с [документацией](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr#sec-10).

```
Country::model()->with('see_places:popular')->findAll();
```